# React Redux Store - Accessed by All Components

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, store

I am relatively new to React and Redux after spending a lot of time in the .net mvc and knockoutjs world. What I am having trouble understanding is how the store is used and how props are passed down between parent and child components.

My first question: if an array of values get sent down from parent to children components via props, do these components do a deep copy and create their own version of this array? If we have a rather large array of values that we want multiple children to have access to, and we send it as props, are we unnecessarily creating extra data or are they just simply referencing the same array?

I'm not sure exactly how the store is used, but could it be used to help the scenario above? If we have some values like a larger array that we want accessed by multiple component children, they could pull them from this globally accessible store?

I would appreciate if somebody could help me wrap my head around these concepts. In my scenario I'm working on we have a table of 30 students each of which gets sent an array of data to help fill in some rows. What I'm afraid we're doing though is giving each student a large amount of data that they don't need if they could pull from the parent or this global store.

```
    <StudentTable
      onSelectAllStudents={this.props.handleSelectAllStudents}
      handleLoadStudentResponses={this.props.handleLoadStudentResponses}
      structures={this.props.structures}
      lessons={this.props.lessons}
      activities={this.props.activities}
      students={this.props.students} />
```

They are creating a table, where each row is a student. The table contains a large amount of data (which is a whole other problem) however what essentially we are doing is for each student we are showing whether they completed a particular activity or not. As you can see in the screenshot they build out a rather complex table. In the StudentTable they loop through students and create a Student component for each row which gets sent in the list of activities so that in the table they can color in a cell based on if the activity is published or not. My main fear was that with each Student component getting the list of activities it was adding a ton of data to memory as opposed to those numerous Student components just referencing some parent array.

[image]

Comment: This is something you should be learning off of a tutorial. The scope of your question is massive.

Comment: I guess my main questions though are just, how does the copy happen when sending to child components between props and secondly is the store meant to be global to all components. I have looked through a couple tutorials but those are the 2 things I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the syntax I've seen, children receive a pointer. Not a new object. Regarding your question about giving 30 students the entire array, you're not approaching data passing correctly. Show us a code snippet and I'll be able to comment more.

Also, redux is not helpful. It can be used, but it's overkill and adds needless complexity. Components with a child-parent relationship can very easily be handled with normal React prop passing. Redux is the go-to option if the components do not have any direct relation.

edit: When referencing elements in an obj, primitives are copied and objects are pointed.

```
const obj = {arrayObject: [], primitiveBoolean: true}
const primitive = obj.primitiveBoolean
const array = obj.arrayObject
primitive = false
console.log(obj.primitiveBoolean); //still true
array.push(10)
console.log(obj.arrayObject); // [10] push changed object's array
```

Comment: I added some data to my original post. We are sending in that big list of activities to each Student as a prop. Also that same activity list could be used to populate the "Select Activity" filter dropdown.

Comment: Also what I was afraid of when I used the react dev tool I went into a particular Student's copy of activities and changed a true/false value and as you can see in the screenshot it changed the color of the first cell under lesson one which I thought meant that the students activities array were not using something like pointers.